# When subtracting years it returns a different result

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm calculating the difference between the date in the database and at the current time. I use this a function called `TimeAgo()` in my PHP code.

`TimeAgo()` code:

```
function TimeAgo ($oldTime, $newTime) 
    {
        $timeCalc = strtotime($newTime) - strtotime($oldTime);
        if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*24*30*12*2)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60/24/30/12) . " years ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*24*30*12)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60/24/30/12) . " year ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*24*30*2)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60/24/30) . " months ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*24*30)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60/24/30) . " month ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*24*2)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60/24) . " days ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*24)){
            $timeCalc = " Yesterday";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60*2)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60) . " hours ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= (60*60)){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60/60) . " hour ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= 60*2){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60) . " minutes ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc >= 60){
            $timeCalc = intval($timeCalc/60) . " minute ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc > 0){
            $timeCalc .= " seconds ago";
        }else if ($timeCalc == 0){
            $timeCalc = "Just now";
        }
        return $timeCalc;
    }
```

Everything works correctly, until I mess around the values in the database. If I set the date to `1901-01-01 00:00:00` it should return the result as `116 years ago` but instead it shows as `48 years ago`.

I'm using this code to show the output:

```
echo TimeAgo($db_user['far_date'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
```

Is there something simple I'm missing when PHP calculates datetimes?

Comment: The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)

Comment: If you need a larger range of dates, then use 64-bit PHP (which works witha 64-bit timestamp value) or use DateTime objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the `PHP` version used. I found online :

> However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

So, this default date occurred 48 years ago , which correspond with what you got.

On newer versions the range is : `Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT.`

If you really want to use this date, then I advise you to do it on MySQL directly , which as I recall using ranges from year 1000 .

Comment: "If you really want to use this date, then I advise you to do it on MySQL directly , which as I recall using ranges from year 0001".. No The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Comment: All he wants to display is the amount of years passed. He doesn't care about the time part. I'll edit in regard to the minimum date, but it's still should be sufficient for him. @RaymondNijland